# Vertical alignment of \vdots in an align environment - a shift of \vdots by half the width of "+"

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

In an `align` environment, I have a sum of an arbitrary number of terms. I want to use `\vdots` to display the ellipses indicating the presence of terms that are not displayed.  As I am vertically aligning the `+`, I would like to have the ellipses displayed by `\vdots` to be centered with respect to `+`. In `TikZ`, thee are commands like `\newlength\width_of_plus_sign` and `\settowidth{\width_of_plus_sign}{$+$}` to do this.  Is there an analog for the `\align` environment?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}


For each integer $2 \leq i \leq n$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n^{i}} \binom{n}{i} &= \frac{1}{n^{i}} \frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{n^{i}} \frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - i + 1)}{i!} \\
&= \frac{1}{i!} \frac{n(n - 1) (n - 2) \cdots (n - (i - 1))}{n^{i}} \\
&= \frac{1}{i!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{i - 1}{n}\right) .
\end{align*}
So,
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^{i}} \binom{n}{i} \\
&\qquad = \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \frac{1}{i!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{i - 1}{n}\right) \\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \\
&\qquad\qquad \!\begin{aligned}[t]
&+ \frac{1}{(k+2)!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{k+1}{n}\right) \\
&+ \frac{1}{(k+3)!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{k+2}{n}\right) \\
&+ \ldots + \frac{1}{n!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{n-1}{n}\right) .
\end{aligned} \\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{k!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \\
&\qquad\qquad \!\begin{aligned}[t]
&\left[\frac{1}{k+1} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \right. \\
&\hphantom{\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{k+1}}\right.}+ \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}  \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{k+1}{n}\right) \\
&\hphantom{\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{k+1}}\right.}+ \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}  \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{k+1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{k+2}{n}\right) \\
&\hphantom{\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{k+1}}\right.}+ \ldots \\
&\hphantom{\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{k+1}}\right.}\left.
+ \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2) \cdots n} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{k+1}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{n-1}{n}\right)
\right] .
\end{aligned}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you might want to look at `\vdotswithin` from the mathtools package

Comment: @daleif  I put `\usepackage{mathtools}` into the preamble and `\vdotswithin{+}` in the `align` environment.  The ellipses are aligned with the center of the first two `+`.  It is not aligned with the other two `+`.  (Take a look at the code that I give in my answer.)

Comment: @daleif   Wait two minutes for me to post an answer.

Comment: Probably because it is meant for relations not bin ops. You might need to copy the definition and in the new version replace mathrel with mathbin

Comment: @daleif  I do not know what you intend by "copy the definition and in the new version replace `mathrel` with `mathbin`."  May you do this for me?  (I can post this as another question.)

Comment: Open mathtools.sty and copy the needed code. Not at a real computer right now, so I cannot do it for you

Comment: @daleif   I do not know where to go to open `mathtools.sty`.  For now, I can use the code provided by `egreg`.  He changed my `\left(` and `\right)` to `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` so that he didn't have to use `\left.`, which is apparently inserting some small extra space.

Answer (score 1):

With some simplifications, both for easing the input and for getting output as intended:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\pterm}[1]{\left(1-\frac{#1}{n}\right)}
\newcommand{\inv}[1]{\frac{1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathmakebox[2em][l]{\sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \inv{n^{i}} \binom{n}{i} \lvert x \rvert^{i}} \\
&= \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \inv{i!} \pterm{1} \pterm{2} \dots \pterm{i - 1} \\
&= \inv{(k+1)!} \pterm{1} \pterm{2} \dots \pterm{k} \\
&\qquad\!\begin{aligned}[t]
  &+ \inv{(k+2)!} \pterm{1} \pterm{2} \dots \pterm{k+1} \\
  &+ \inv{(k+3)!} \pterm{1} \pterm{2} \dots \pterm{k+2} \\
  &+ \dots + \inv{n!} \pterm{1} \pterm{2} \dots \pterm{n-1} .
\end{aligned} \\
&= \!\begin{aligned}[t]
  \inv{k!}
    & \pterm{1} \pterm{2} \dots \pterm{k} \\
    &\biggl[\inv{k+1} \pterm{k}\\
    &\hphantom{\biggl[} + \inv{(k+1)(k+2)}  \pterm{k} \pterm{k+1} \\
    &\hphantom{\biggl[}+ \inv{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}  \pterm{k} \pterm{k+1} \pterm{k+2} \\
    &\phantom{\biggl[}+ {} \\[-2ex]
    &\hphantom{\biggl[}\vdotswithin{+} \\[-2ex]
    &\phantom{\biggl[}+ {}\\
    &\hphantom{\biggl[}
     + \inv{(k+1)(k+2) \dots n} \pterm{k} \pterm{k+1} \dots \pterm{n-1}\biggr] .
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed all `\ldots` and `\cdots` to `\dots`; you seem to be using them the other way around than usual.

Comment: The first "thing" I noticed about your code is that you replaced the `left.` with `\biggl[`.  It does give me the display that I want.  (Are`\biggl(` and `\biggr)` designed to give parentheses around a displayed fraction?)  My concern is that this code will not apply to quotients in which I have a quotient, in `displaystyle`, in the "numerator" and  a quotient, in `displaystyle`, in the "denominator."  In that case, I would have to use the pair `\left(` and `\right)` or the pair `\left.` and `\right)`.

Comment: @user74973 `\biggl` and `\biggr` do “manual sizing”. Not sure about the rest of the comment.

Comment: What do you intend by "manual sizing"?  I thought that I remember reading in the `TeX` manual that `\biggl` gave a parenthesis or brace of an exact size, dependent on the font.

Comment: @user74973 Yes, that's the idea: *you* choose the size, not like with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: It seems that `LaTeX` puts in some extra horizontal spacing with `\left.`.  The ellipses and plus signs in my code should be aligned.  Well, for this display, your suggestion does give me what I want.

Comment: By the way, I see that I have `\lvert x \rvert^{i}}` in the first line of the expression but not in the other lines.  I forgot to include this in the other lines.  The easiest edit is to delete this from the first line.  I am going to delete it from the first line of the post.  You may want to delete it from the code in your reply.

Comment: @user74973 Lack of math correctness is not a problem: it's just an example of how to code something. And yes, `\left.` and `\right.` add some space.

Comment: I like the party hat on your tag - or whatever you call it.  You'll be celebrating New Year's Eve before I will.  (I am in New York.)  Happy New Year!

Comment: @egreg couldn't you just have used an extra aligned? Getting rid of the phantoms

Comment: @daleif Maybe, but it doesn't seem a big deal. A couple of `\vphantom` tokens would be needed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is prompted by the comment from `daleif`.  I had to add `mathtools` to the preamble.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^{i}} \binom{n}{i} \vert x \vert^{i} \\
&\qquad = \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \frac{1}{i!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{i - 1}{n}\right) \\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \\
&\qquad\qquad \!\begin{aligned}[t]
&+ \frac{1}{(k+2)!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{k+1}{n}\right) \\
&+ \frac{1}{(k+3)!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{k+2}{n}\right) \\
&+ \ldots + \frac{1}{n!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{n-1}{n}\right) .
\end{aligned} \\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{k!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \\
&\qquad\qquad \!\begin{aligned}[t]
&\left[\frac{1}{k+1} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \right. \\
&\hphantom{\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{k+1}}\right.}+ \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}  \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{k+1}{n}\right) \\
&\hphantom{\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{k+1}}\right.}+ \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}  \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{k+1}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{k+2}{n}\right) \\
&\hphantom{\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{k+1}}\right.}+ \\
&\hphantom{\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{k+1}}\right.}\vdotswithin{+} \\
&\hphantom{\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{k+1}}\right.}+ \\
&\hphantom{\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{k+1}}\right.}\left.
+ \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2) \cdots n} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) \left(1 - \frac{k+1}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{n-1}{n}\right)
\right] .
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are all the plus signs not vertically aligned?